# Django Orm Related Table Condition

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

I have table foo which is related to table bar, how can I make it in Django Orm to use
column from related table for filter?

Raw Query:

```
select a.* from foo as a, bar as b where a.bar_id = b.id and b.is_deleted = 0
```

Django Orm:

```
Foo.objects.filter(<bar_is_deleted>=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Foo.objects.filter(bar__is_deleted=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

You use the double-underscore syntax.

```
Foo.objects.filter(bar__is_deleted=0)
```